# Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters when installing go-1.17 via Jenkins tool

Tags: go, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, agent

**Hi, i'm trying to set up go-1.17 env to a jenkins agent but i have an issue related to unmappable characters
Is there are any solution ?**

Output:

```
Unpacking Go from https://golang.org/dl/go1.17.linux-amd64.tar.gz to /home/ubuntu/Jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/go-1.17 on api2
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from <some_ip>
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1797)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1165)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1154)
        at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:1010)
        at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:946)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstaller.performInstallation(GolangInstaller.java:57)
        at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:70)
        at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:107)
        at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:220)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation.forNode(GolangInstallation.java:44)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation.forNode(GolangInstallation.java:22)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ToolStep$Execution.run(ToolStep.java:155)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ToolStep$Execution.run(ToolStep.java:136)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: /home/ubuntu/Jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/go-1.17/go/test/fixedbugs/issue27836.dir/Äfoo.go
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        go 'go-1.17'
    }
    environment {
        GO111MODULE = 'on'
    }
    stages {
    stage('Setting up dependencies'){
        steps {
            echo 'Setting up dependencies'
            sh 'go mod vendor'
        }
    }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running build automation'
                sh 'go build -o main'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Agent and master file encodings are UTF-8 (Checked via system information)

Answer (score 2):

In the agent configuration click **Advanced** and in **JWM Options** type

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

Then reconnect your agent and it will probably OK

Comment: The "-Dsun.jnu.encoding" command-line option is no longer taken into account on AdoptJDK 11+. You have to set LANG=xx_xx.UTF-8 before you launch your java process in order to set the value of sun.jnu.encoding to an UTF-8 character set.